# sonarqube-You must install a plugin that supports the language ‘’python‘’

Tags: python, java, plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

when I use sonar-project.properties ：

```
sonar.projectKey=gauge
sonar.sources=step_impl/
sonar.language=python
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

I got error msg below：

```
01:05:46 INFO: Final Memory: 12M/185M
01:05:46 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
01:05:46 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
01:05:46 ERROR: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'python'
01:05:46 ERROR: 
01:05:46 ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Answer (score 0):

use：
sonar.language=py

the problem was solved!

It sounds like that sonar.language needs to be set to the checked scripts suffix.
Not the language name itself!